# Recipe / Bill of Materials MySQL Query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I am writing a Bill of Materials/Recipe App for Minecraft in Node.js, Express, React and MySQL.

I have what I think is a good structure for the database with the tables, but I am running into an issue with the Queries I need to run. Here is an example of what I am trying to do with an example output (I know the recipe is not correct MC players).

Ingredients Table:

```
RECIPE        || INGREDIENT   || QTY || TYPE
Piston        || Redstone     ||  1  || RM
Piston        || Iron Ingot   ||  1  || RM
Piston        || Wood Planks  ||  3  || RM
Piston        || Stone        ||  4  || RM
Sticky Piston || Piston       ||  2  || CO
Sticky Piston || Slimeball    ||  1  || RM
```

What I want is that when I Query for a Sticky Piston, there is a table returned with all of the required components summed together (on top) and all of the required Raw Materials summed together (below).

Example Required Output in Table format or JSON format:

```
INGREDIENT   || QTY || TYPE
Piston       ||  2  || CO
Redstone     ||  2  || RM
Iron Ingot   ||  2  || RM
Wood Planks  ||  6  || RM
Stone        ||  8  || RM
Slimeball    ||  1  || RM


[
    {
        "Ingredient": "Piston",
        "Qty": 2,
        "Type": CO
    },
    {
        "Ingredient": "Redstone",
        "Qty": 2,
        "Type": RM
    },
    {
        "Ingredient": "Iron Ingot",
        "Qty": 2,
        "Type": RM
    },
    {
        "Ingredient": "Wood Planks",
        "Qty": 6,
        "Type": RM
    },
    {
        "Ingredient": "Stone",
        "Qty": 8,
        "Type": RM
    },
    {
        "Ingredient": "Slimeball",
        "Qty": 2,
        "Type": RM
    }
]
```

I assume it is a JOIN with some other fancy stuff that can do it all inside of MYSQL syntax, but I cannot figure it out despite two days of trying out different combinations.

Alternatively, I would be fine if instead of using MYSQL syntax, that JS was used that I can run on my Node.js server.

Here is a modified version of the schema per instructions from below. This is what my understanding of the relationship should be, but I still cannot figure out how to return all of the required resources when recipes are made up of other components that require other Materials as well.

```
CREATE TABLE Ingredients
(
  MaterialID    INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Material      VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  MaterialImage VARCHAR(250),
  PRIMARY KEY (MaterialID)
);

CREATE TABLE Recipes
(
  RecipeID      INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Recipe        VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ComponentID)
);

CREATE TABLE Recipes_Ingredients
(
  RecipeID      INT unsigned NOT NULL,
  MaterialID    INT unsigned NOT NULL,
  Quantity      INT unsigned NOT NULL
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a simple query without a join. Just a where against recipe with an order by. Edit your question and show the table schema(s) involved, and how they relate to each other if you really think a join is needed. Also, add the query you have tried

Comment: You are probably right, I have other tables, but no need to join them. I can easily get a SELECT WHERE the Recipe = the one I am looking for, but then how do I get the components to get their Raw Materials to return as well? And then add the quantities together?

Comment: Edit your question and show the schema of your table. If all you need to do is group by an ingredient and sum the quantities, that's pretty trivial, but I would need to see the table schema

Comment: You really need to normalize your ingredients table. What this means is that ot should really be split up into 3 tables. An ingredients table and a recipe table. The ingredients and reciprs tables would consist of only an integer ID and a name. While the third table would bridge them. The third table would contain the ID of the recipe and the ID of the material used for that recipe.

Comment: Kodos, I understand that is the way that it should be done. Can you explain why it should be done that way? I don't know why it would be an advantage, but I am speaking from ignorance of not understanding and would love to understand why it is better.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your message until now. One reason why it's better is for storage. You are repeating the same string over and over (i.e. 'Piston' or 'Sticky Piston') which uses  6+ bytes each multiplied by the number of rows you use. It's much better to use a "bridge" table which joins the ingredients and recipes using an integer to represent ingredients and recipes (which is only 4 bytes for each combination). Also, what if you wanted to rename one of the ingredients/recipes? If you normalize, you only have to update one record vs. x number of records.

Comment: That makes good sense @Kodos. Is there a utility to use, or a trick that is common among database experts in order to easily know what information the ID's belong to? I had a hard time trying to create the recipes when I constantly had to look up the corresponding ID number, but I am sure there is a more efficient way of handling that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE/EDIT:**

**Updated to correct calculation of the Quantity**

I've changed your table arrangement to better match the data you are trying to represent. Since a "recipe" can also be a "material", I've eliminated the recipe table, and stored that data in the materials table.

I also created a SQL Fiddle so you can play with the query and fine tune the results.

The first query below returns all "recipes" and their components. To get just one particular recipe, just add a condition to the where clause that selects the particular recipe.

If you would prefer to have the components listed in a single field, with one row per recipe, you can use the GROUP_CONCAT function and change the group by clause.

The second query below illustrates the GROUP_CONCAT function. It also shows how to change missing sub-ingredients from NULL to 'None'

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4caf44/6)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE `Ingredients`
(
  `MaterialID`      INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Material`        VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `MaterialImage`   VARCHAR(250),
  `IsRecipe`        TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MaterialID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Recipes_Ingredients`
(
  `id`              INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RecipeID`        INT unsigned NOT NULL,
  `MaterialID`      INT unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Quantity`        INT unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `Ingredients`
(`MaterialID`,`Material`,`MaterialImage`,`IsRecipe`)
VALUES
(1,'Redstone','redstone.jpg',0),
(2,'Iron Ingot','ironingot.jpg',0),
(3,'Wood Planks','woodplanks.jpg',0),
(4,'Stone','stone.jpg',0),
(5,'Slimeball','slimeball.jpg',0),
(6,'Piston','piston.jpg',1),
(7,'Sticky Piston','stickypiston.jpg',1),
(8,'Sticky Piston 2','stickypiston2.jpg',1);


INSERT INTO `Recipes_Ingredients`
(`RecipeID`,`MaterialID`,`Quantity`)
VALUES
(6,1,1),
(6,2,1),
(6,3,3),
(6,4,4),
(7,6,1),
(7,5,1),
(8,6,2),
(8,5,1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  a.`MaterialID`,
  c.`MaterialID`,
  a.`Material` as `Recipe`,
  a.`MaterialImage` as `RecipeImage`,
  c.`Material` as `Ingredient`,
  b.`Quantity` as `FirstIngredientQuantity`,
  c.`MaterialImage` as `IngredientImage`,
  IF(d.`Quantity` IS NULL,SUM(b.`Quantity`),COALESCE(d.`Quantity`,0)*b.`Quantity`) as `Quantity`,
  e.`Material` as `Ingredient`,
  e.`MaterialImage` as `MaterialImage`
FROM `Ingredients` a
LEFT JOIN `Recipes_Ingredients` b
ON b.`RecipeID` = a.`MaterialID`
LEFT JOIN `Ingredients` c
ON c.`MaterialID` = b.`MaterialID`
LEFT JOIN `Recipes_Ingredients` d
ON d.`RecipeID` = c.`MaterialID`
LEFT JOIN `Ingredients` e
ON e.`MaterialID` = d.`MaterialID` AND c.`IsRecipe` = 1
WHERE a.`IsRecipe` = 1 AND a.`MaterialID` in (7,8)
GROUP BY a.`MaterialID`,c.`MaterialID`,e.`MaterialID`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4caf44/6/0)**:

```
| MaterialID | MaterialID |          Recipe |       RecipeImage | Ingredient | FirstIngredientQuantity | IngredientImage | Quantity |  Ingredient |  MaterialImage |
|------------|------------|-----------------|-------------------|------------|-------------------------|-----------------|----------|-------------|----------------|
|          7 |          5 |   Sticky Piston |  stickypiston.jpg |  Slimeball |                       1 |   slimeball.jpg |        1 |      (null) |         (null) |
|          7 |          6 |   Sticky Piston |  stickypiston.jpg |     Piston |                       1 |      piston.jpg |        1 |    Redstone |   redstone.jpg |
|          7 |          6 |   Sticky Piston |  stickypiston.jpg |     Piston |                       1 |      piston.jpg |        1 |  Iron Ingot |  ironingot.jpg |
|          7 |          6 |   Sticky Piston |  stickypiston.jpg |     Piston |                       1 |      piston.jpg |        3 | Wood Planks | woodplanks.jpg |
|          7 |          6 |   Sticky Piston |  stickypiston.jpg |     Piston |                       1 |      piston.jpg |        4 |       Stone |      stone.jpg |
|          8 |          5 | Sticky Piston 2 | stickypiston2.jpg |  Slimeball |                       1 |   slimeball.jpg |        1 |      (null) |         (null) |
|          8 |          6 | Sticky Piston 2 | stickypiston2.jpg |     Piston |                       2 |      piston.jpg |        2 |    Redstone |   redstone.jpg |
|          8 |          6 | Sticky Piston 2 | stickypiston2.jpg |     Piston |                       2 |      piston.jpg |        2 |  Iron Ingot |  ironingot.jpg |
|          8 |          6 | Sticky Piston 2 | stickypiston2.jpg |     Piston |                       2 |      piston.jpg |        6 | Wood Planks | woodplanks.jpg |
|          8 |          6 | Sticky Piston 2 | stickypiston2.jpg |     Piston |                       2 |      piston.jpg |        8 |       Stone |      stone.jpg |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT
  a.`MaterialID`,
  c.`MaterialID`,
  a.`Material` as `Recipe`,
  a.`MaterialImage` as `RecipeImage`,
  c.`Material` as `Ingredient`,
  c.`MaterialImage` as `MaterialImage`,
  SUM(b.`Quantity` + COALESCE(d.`Quantity`,0)) as `Quantity`,
  COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(e.`Material`,' (',b.`Quantity` * d.`Quantity`,') [',e.`MaterialImage`,']')),'None') as `Ingredients`
FROM `Ingredients` a
LEFT JOIN `Recipes_Ingredients` b
ON b.`RecipeID` = a.`MaterialID`
LEFT JOIN `Ingredients` c
ON c.`MaterialID` = b.`MaterialID`
LEFT JOIN `Recipes_Ingredients` d
ON d.`RecipeID` = c.`MaterialID`
LEFT JOIN `Ingredients` e
ON e.`MaterialID` = d.`MaterialID` AND c.`IsRecipe` = 1
WHERE a.`IsRecipe` = 1
GROUP BY a.`MaterialID`,c.`MaterialID`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4caf44/6/1)**:

```
| MaterialID | MaterialID |          Recipe |       RecipeImage |  Ingredient |  MaterialImage | Quantity |                                                                                                       Ingredients |
|------------|------------|-----------------|-------------------|-------------|----------------|----------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|          6 |          1 |          Piston |        piston.jpg |    Redstone |   redstone.jpg |        1 |                                                                                                              None |
|          6 |          2 |          Piston |        piston.jpg |  Iron Ingot |  ironingot.jpg |        1 |                                                                                                              None |
|          6 |          3 |          Piston |        piston.jpg | Wood Planks | woodplanks.jpg |        3 |                                                                                                              None |
|          6 |          4 |          Piston |        piston.jpg |       Stone |      stone.jpg |        4 |                                                                                                              None |
|          7 |          5 |   Sticky Piston |  stickypiston.jpg |   Slimeball |  slimeball.jpg |        1 |                                                                                                              None |
|          7 |          6 |   Sticky Piston |  stickypiston.jpg |      Piston |     piston.jpg |       13 | Redstone (1) [redstone.jpg],Iron Ingot (1) [ironingot.jpg],Wood Planks (3) [woodplanks.jpg],Stone (4) [stone.jpg] |
|          8 |          5 | Sticky Piston 2 | stickypiston2.jpg |   Slimeball |  slimeball.jpg |        1 |                                                                                                              None |
|          8 |          6 | Sticky Piston 2 | stickypiston2.jpg |      Piston |     piston.jpg |       17 | Redstone (2) [redstone.jpg],Iron Ingot (2) [ironingot.jpg],Wood Planks (6) [woodplanks.jpg],Stone (8) [stone.jpg] |
```

Comment: This only returns the direct ingredients for a Sticky Piston, it does not break out the ingredients also required to craft a Piston which is an ingredient in the Sticky Piston.

Comment: As per @Kodos comment, your data should be normalized. You do not want to link tables using text values. If not the 3 tables he suggested, then at least a unique auto increment key, and a integer key for "sub-ingredients". Linking rows based on a text key uses more resources on every query, and is prone to errors. For example "Piston" doesn't equal "piston". It would help if your question included the schema of the table. The schema could be as simple as showing the create table statement.

Comment: OK, I updated the original post with Schema. Hopefully this is the way the database should be organized.

Comment: Based on your update to your question, I've updated the answer. It also suggests a change to your schema and how you store your data that should improve performance and make the data easier to maintain. I also created a SQL Fiddle so you can play around with the two queries.

Comment: This is awesome! The first query is very close to what I am looking for. I appreciate the fiddle as well! The only thing that is missing from the first Query is that the sums are off. They are not returning the right amounts for the recipe and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: It is adding one to each quantity of the raw materials that make up the Piston, and it is also not returning the Piston as a required ingredient.

Comment: See the updated [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4caf44/6/0). I also added another recipe that has two pistons just to check the math. See the updated answer above.

Comment: Perfect! Marked as accepted and I voted you up, but I don't have enough rep for it to show. Last question...How can I make it so I can pass in a quantity of the main recipe that would multiply all values for sub ingredients properly?

Comment: That would more properly be done in the calling language, or in a MySQL function or procedure.